# How to hook into Android Application lifecycle?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, background-foreground

Android supports hooking into the `Activity` lifecycle through [`Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html) but I couldn't find a way to *easily* hook into the `Application` one. Why isn't there a similar interface for the `Application` lifecycle?

I want to know if an app is in background/foreground and I don't want to do the count manually (feasible using the [`Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html)).

I'm developing an Android library and one of the use cases requires knowing if the app which includes the lib is in background/foreground.

I saw that there is an [`ApplicationLifecycleCallback`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/runner/lifecycle/ApplicationLifecycleCallback.html) interface available in the `android.support.test.runner.lifecycle` package (only for testing). Why not exposing something similar within the `android.app` package as `Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks`?

How to accomplish my use case? How would you implement it?

Any hints/ideas/workarounds would be more than welcome. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I want to know if an app is in background/foreground and I don't want to do the count manually (feasible using the Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks).

If that is how you are defining "`Application` lifecycle", [use `ProcessLifecycleOwner`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ProcessLifecycleOwner.html) from the Architecture Components.

Comment: damn, you'r fast ;-) Everytime i start writing the answer you'r faster. Good job :)

Comment: > damn, you'r fast ;-)

@EmanuelSeibold very true

@CommonsWare didn't know about `ProcessLifecycleOwner`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Guardiola31337: It's pretty new, as the Architecture Components were first released in May 2017. And, at the present time, they are still in an alpha state, so YMMV. FWIW, [here is a sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-androidarch/tree/v0.2/General/ProcessLifecycle) demonstrating its use.